# Giant invisible div covers whole webpage

Tags: html, css

Me and a few classmates are working on a project where we have to make a webshop.
We are working with Github so everyone has the latest version. Everyone is using Google Chrome, so am I. On my classmate's browsers the webshop works just fine. And on mine there is a giant invisible div that covers the whole page so I can't click on anything.

This is the div I'm taking about:

```
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 1001px;"></div>
```

If I use "Inspect Element" this div will be shown almost at the bottom of the html code. (Just above the  tag. It also takes his with from the container we use. And on the browsers of my classmates the whole div doesn't excist!

So my question is: Is there anyone that knows how to fix this?

EDIT: In IE it works just fine for me too. Only Google Chrome creates this weird div.

Comment: Did you try updating your google chrome?

Comment: If it works on others Chrome I suggest you to disable all plugins and extensions of you Chrome browser and retry.

Comment: @CaryBondoc Yes I have. Out of nowhere it happened, I didn't change anything about the code. That's the weirdest thing.

Comment: @wbjari, the last thing that pops in my mind is the extension in your google chrome just like what Maxime suggested.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of extension named "smooth scroll" on google chrome, try disabled or remove it